# improving battery life for macBook Air M1

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, apple-silicon

Given that:

1. My MacBook Air M1 chip has more than 70% battery
2. The charging port is nearby and charging my Macbook Air while working does no bother me.

So in order to have prolonged battery life what should be done:

1. While working with MacBook Air M1 chip, continue charging it whenever possible irrespective of battery level.

OR

2. Charge battery only when below some threshold say 10%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the Mac!  But you can help it with:

- Make sure "Optimized battery charging" is on.  System Preferences > Battery.
- Avoid having power connected *all* the time, though this is mitigated by macOS and the setting optimise battery charging.
- Avoid letting the battery go below 25%, but if needed sometimes don't worry.
- If you are going to turn it off for many weeks, let it run down to 60% before turning it off.
- Avoid high temperatures by keeping air flow around the MacBook - for example, don't rest it for long on soft bed covers.

Apple don't say, but battery is probably happiest between 40% and 80%.

Edit:

Apple are very reticent about precise advice regarding battery health. The most recent [Apple battery support note](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204054) has no advice on maximising battery health - only about battery life (time usable on battery power).  The only reference to battery health is the tick box for "Optimized battery charging".

[How to Prolong Lithium-based batteries](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) is a relatively recent general discussion of strategies to assist battery health. In particular Figure 6 shows the effect on batteries due to to different use and charging strategies with maximum battery lifetime being from keeping the battery between 65% and 75% at all times.  Read this (and some of its links) with interest and to gain some understanding of battery performance - but not to hamper use of the new MacBook Air.

Comment: @MohitLamba - just remember that when not on power connected you won't get full performance..

Comment: @Gilby So as a rule of thumb can I say that I should start charging my battery only when below 40%. Above 50% use Mac without charging.

Comment: @MohitLamba I would say that's an unnecessary strategy. Plug it in if you're going to be using it near a power point for some time. Use it unplugged if that's more convenient. You're over-thinking it.

Comment: @Gilby Why not always on the electricity? Also, the best value is 30% - 80% for battery life

Comment: @MohitLamba Don't need to be precise about charging.  Just avoid the extremes of very low and always 100%.  The battery likes to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Your new M1 Mac not only has sophisticated battery management software, but is also one of the most efficient laptops on the planet.

You don't need to do anything. Just use it as you need. There is very little you can do to improve (or worsen) the battery's life.

Of course, keeping it plugged it will reduce the number of charging cycles, but in all likelihood, a 5-year-old battery will need servicing, regardless of whether it has 50 cycles or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Gilby said it all, maybe except one more. If you live somewhere where temperature drops below 5 deg celsius make sure to keep your laptop warm when transporting it. Just one hour in temps around zero or below can easily kill your battery. It just happened to me yesterday. From perfect condition to does not last even two minutes.

This alone can kill perfect battery quickly. I managed my battery for 3 years making all the mentioned steps.